# Java ClassLoader stops working when used in new Thread (Runnable)

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse-plugin, osgi, classloader

I'm developing an eclipse plugin. When the plugin is run (e.g. in a debugging instance of eclipse), it loads certain classes from all java-projects in the debugging workspace. Reflection is used for this purpose. To get a better idea of what I'm doing here is some code:

```
for (IPath outDir : _outputDirs)
{
    IPath fullTestPackageDir = outDir.append(testPackageDir);
    File dir = fullTestPackageDir.toFile();
    if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())
    {
        for (File classFile : dir.listFiles())
        {
            String binaryClassName = packageName + "." + FileUtils.getNameWithoutExtension(classFile);
            Class<ITest> testClass = tryLoadClass(binaryClassName, ITest.class);
            if (testClass != null)
            {
                testClasses.add(testClass);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my implementation of `tryLoadClass` used above, as requested in the comments (not much magic at all). The _urlClassLoader is created from an array of `URL`s (output folders of java-projects in the debugging workspace) and has current thread's context ClassLoader as parent.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> Class<T> tryLoadClass(String binaryClassName, Class<T> baseType)
{
    try
    {
        Class<?> testClass = _urlClassLoader.loadClass(binaryClassName);

        if (!baseType.isAssignableFrom(testClass))
            return null;

        return (Class<T>)testClass;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println("class not found");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Later, these classes are instantiated and a function (`run`) is called:

```
Class<ITest> testClass = testClasses.get(i);

try
{
    ITest test = testClass.getConstructor(IRuntime.class).newInstance(_runtime);
    test.run();
}
catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the bundle of the plugin there are several utility classes, e.g. `MyUtil`, which are exported by the plugin, and can be referenced by the classes loaded above. Precisely, `MyUtil` is referenced in the `run` function.

Everything works fine with the code above. But if I'm moving `test.run()` into another Thread, I get a ClassNotFoundException for `MyUtil`. Here's the code again (it is almost the same as above, only the 6th line is replaced). `ITest` inherits from `Runnable`:

```
Class<ITest> testClass = testClasses.get(i);

try
{
    ITest test = testClass.getConstructor(IRuntime.class).newInstance(_runtime);
    Thread thread = new Thread(test, "TestThread");
    thread.start();
}
catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I already tried a lots of things, like getting the current thread's `ContextClassLoader` and passing it to the new thread, but not luck. What I found out is that I can use the current thread's `ContextClassLoader` explicitly to load `MyUtil`, but only when it is used from within the original thread. If I pass that ClassLoader into the new thread, it stops working.

I think my problem is that I have some wrong understanding of how ClassLoaders work...

Here are some more details about the Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.my.company.MyPlugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 2 more
```

Because there has been a question about how "de.my.company.MyPlugin" is being loaded: it's just in the bundle/plugin, which is required by java projects in the debugging workspace, thus I think it's on the "base" classpath (don't know the right terminology here...)

/edit:
I just realized that I did not mention something that might be important: `test.run()` (as well as starting the new thread) is done in the context of an Eclipse `Job`. But I think I already counted this out: the problem remains the same when I remove the `Job`-context (issue the code directly from within the Handler of an Eclipse command). However, the problem does not exist, if the `ITest` implementation is instantiated normally (i.e. in the eclipse debugging instance; I tested it within a simple `main()` function).

I think the problem is caused by the fact that my custom `_urlClassLoader` is used to load `ITest`. Because Java tries to load any referenced classes using the class-loader that loaded the container class in the very beginning (afaik), my _urlClassLoader would be used again. The _urlClassLoader alone, however, cannot load the requested classes (it only has the output folders of other java projects on its "classpath"). Instead, its parent must be used. If I understood everything right this should happen automatically, but it is exactly this part that doesn't work with the new thread anymore...

Comment: Can you tell us more about `tryLoadClass`? where is the class `de.my.company.MyPlugin` present and how it is added to classpath of `URLClassLoader`(as seen in the exception trace)?

Comment: Can you verify the URLClassloader is not closed before the Thread finishes running? I ask because URLClassloader is supposed to be closed after usage and `test.run()` will block until all work is done, but `thread.start()` runs async.

Comment: The strange thing about your issue is that you are creating the `Thread` at a place where the entire class loading has been finished. It’s no wonder that playing around with the new `Thread`’s context loader doesn’t solve the problem, you create the `Thread` by passing an *instance* of your class to its constructor so how should anything you do with that `Thread` later on influence the *loading* of that class? You should track down the place at which the `ClassNotFoundException` really occurs, it can’t be the new thread. *If* it is the new thread, it hasn’t anything to do with the posted code.

Comment: @vanOekel: the original Thread is not closed; I've inserted an infinite loop after `thread.start()`.
@Holger: I can switch between "everything's working" and `ClassNotFoundException` by simply replacing `test.run()` with the two lines of code that construct and start the new thread. I also think that there shouldn't be any difference regarding class-loading at this point of time.

Comment: @Holger: i added some information at the very end of my question; I think the problem is related to the fact that the code, which is actually executed (= implementation of ´ITest.run()´), is loaded differently than the VM would do it (using the _urlClassLoader). At least, if I instantiate an ITest implementation normally (i.e. in the eclipse debugging instance), the class-loading problem does not exist.

Comment: @TheFish: Please, add the *full* stack trace. It looks like your `IRuntime` class is trying to load the `MyPlugin` class, directly or indirectly, but *dynamically*.

Comment: Have you checked this article (http://book.javanb.com/eclipse-rich-client-platform-designing-coding-and-packaging-java-applications-oct-2005/ch20lev1sec5.html)? It might be helpful to understand common class loading issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not deep into the OSGi way of loading classes but I know the standard mechanism good enough to state the following things:

- The way the JVM resolves classes (using the referrer’s `ClassLoader`) does not change when using a different `Thread`
- The delegation to the parent loader implemented by the `URLClassLoader` happens unconditionally

So if these parts do not change, it’s the parent loader provided by the OSGi  framework which changes its behavior. I found [this blog entry](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Context_Class_Loader_Enhancements#Context_Finder_2) describing a mechanism that would fit into the observed behavior:

> ### Context Finder
>
> The context finder is a kind of ClassLoader that is installed by the Equinox Framework as the default context classloader. When invoked, it searches down the Java execution stack for a classloader other than the system classloader.

So when you start a new `Thread` providing the `Runnable` you have loaded dynamically using your `URLClassLoader`, there is no bundle in the stack trace of that `Thread` that can be used as context.

A simple work-around could be adding code from your bundle to the stack trace of the new `Thread`, i.e. change

```
Thread thread = new Thread(test, "TestThread");
```

into

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() { test.run(); }
}, "TestThread");
```

<sup>Of course, `test` must be changed to `final`</sup>

That way your caller (the anonymous inner class) originating from your Eclipse plugin is on the top of the new `Thread`’s stack. Since your `URLClassLoader`’s parent is already initialized to the OSGi class loader it should not be necessary to set the context class loader (unless there’s some dynamic loading using the thread context loader in the loaded code).

Comment: Perfect! I just tried it out, but I was already very confident after reading your explanation. What do you think would be the best approach to continue? The simple work-around you suggested is fine, but I'd prefer to install a ClassLoader that finds classes in my bundle without having to look at the stack trace. Writing my own ClassLoader implementation for this purpose feels like re-inventing the wheel...

Comment: As said, I’m not deep into the OSGi thing, but maybe calling `getClass().getClassLoader()` on a class of your plugin will give you a `ClassLoader` tied to your plugin rather than the default loader with that searching algorithm. If so, using that `ClassLoader` as the parent of your `URLClassLoader` would solve the problem.